# Using binary tree to simulate relational database

Tags: java, mysql, binary-tree

I want to simulate the mysql or sql database operations like creating database tables rows inserting updating searching with the binary tree structure and store my data in file using java . the problem is that i didn't get how can i do this passing by the binary tree which is required to complete that home work.

Comment: Break it down. Start by simulating `SELECT key,value FROM tbl WHERE key='constant'` by traversing your binary tree in O(log n) time to find the key  you want. When you get that to work you'll have a better vision for how to simulate the other parts of RDMS functionality called for in your assignment.

Comment: Hello . thank you so much for this hint . also i need to know how to presente the columns . let's consider that the client wants to create table with 5 columns how can i presente this .